# Intermittent "No such file or directory" and permission errors when opening files (in a loop) on mounted FTP drive (linux)? Sync issue?

Tags: python, ftp, synchronization, network-drive

Getting errors like

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/files/file.pdf'

when trying to loop through and open files in a mounted FTP drive (mounted via `curlftpfs 'myuser:mypassword'@MY.SERVER.IP /path/to/files`). **I suspect sync issues**, as the mounted drive is from another server on our network.

I can see that the file is there, can open it manually, can `ls '/path/to/files/file.pdf'` to see the file, but when executing...

```py
FILES = os.listdir('/path/to/files')
FILES.sort()
.
.
.
for file in FILES:
    with open(os.path.join('/path/to/files', 'file.pdf'), 'rb') as fd:
        do stuff
```

... I *sometimes* get the `FileNotFOundError`.

More confusing, I **can actually open this file (using the same path string that the error message tells me is not a file or directory) separately by just starting a python interactive shell** and run something like...

```py
fd = open('/path/to/files/file.pdf', 'rb')
fd.read()
```

...so IDK what the issue could be when reading it in a list of files.

Any debugging ideas or ideas of what could be causing this? Could there be some kind of timing/sync issues between reading the files on the mounted FTP drive vs the script that is running locally (and how to fix)?

* UPDATE:

Oddly, printing the target path before trying to open the file like...

```py
print(os.path.join('/path/to/files', 'file.pdf'))
time.sleep(2)  # giving even more time after initial access
with open(os.path.join('/path/to/files', 'file.pdf'), 'rb') as fd:
    do stuff
```

...seems to help (kinda). Now *also* randomly throws `PermissionError`s for random files that I had no problem reading before (still occasionally throws `FileNotFoundError`s) and that I can actually open when accessing individually in python interactive shell. **Makes me moreso think it is some kind of sync issue**. Will need to investigate more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `os.path` is a module, it will return an error if you use it like `os.path('/path/to/files/file.pdf')`
But I think it's not the cause of `FileNotFOundError`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my post. Edited

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe i'll double check if there's a problem with `os.path.join('/path/to/files', 'file.pdf')` ; if `print(os.path.join('/path/to/files', 'file.pdf'))` and `ls (the path)`, can you see the file as well?

Comment: hmmm, printing the target path before trying to open it actually seems to help (kinda; now randomly throws `PermissionError`s for random files). Makes me think it is some kind of sync issue. Will need to investigate more.